# Automapper override values which are not in source

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

Hi have a problem with auomapper where i try to use the Automapper.Mapper(src, dest) without loosing the values in the dest after doing the mapping.

I have a class which has a list of objects like below

```
public class UpdateShipmentDetailDto
    {
        public bool IsDocument { get; set; }

        public List<UpdateItemDetailDto> ItemDetails { get; set; } = new();

    }
```

which i want to map to

```
public class SCS_OUT_Manifest
    {
        public Guid ManifestId { get; set; }
       

        public ICollection<SCS_OUT_ManifestItem> SCS_OUT_ManifestItems { get; set; } = new List<SCS_OUT_ManifestItem>();
    }
```

The UpdateItemDetailDto class looks like this

```
public class UpdateItemDetailDto
    {
        public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
        public Guid UnitsId { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemValue { get; set; }
    }
```

And the SCS_OUT_ManifestItem class looke like

```
 public class SCS_OUT_ManifestItem
    {
        public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
        public Guid ManifestId { get; set; }
        public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
        public Guid UnitsId { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemValue { get; set; }
}
```

Im performing a maaping like below, which map from ItemDetails (which is a list) to SCS_OUT_ManifestItems (which is also a ICollection).

```
 _mapper.Map(updateShipmentDetailDto.ItemDetails, manifest.SCS_OUT_ManifestItems);
```

The problem after mapping is done the properties which in the destination collection are set to the default values.

for example the `ManifestId` inthe SCS_OUT_ManifestItem `manifest.SCS_OUT_ManifestItems` which is not in `updateShipmentDetailDto.ItemDetails` is set to its default `Guid` value `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.

But if i run this in a loop like below it works.

```
foreach (var item in manifest.SCS_OUT_ManifestItems)
            {

                _mapper.Map(updateShipmentDetailDto.ItemDetails.Single(s => s.ItemId == item.ItemId), item);

            }
```

Please help! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try map your lists and your itens and use the same name ÏtemDetails" in both lists.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
{
    cfg.CreateMap<UpdateItemDetailDto, SCS_OUT_ManifestItem>();
    cfg.CreateMap<UpdateShipmentDetailDto, SCS_OUT_Manifest>();
});
var _mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var updateShipmentDetailDto = new UpdateShipmentDetailDto();
var updateItemDetailDto = new UpdateItemDetailDto();
var manifest = new SCS_OUT_Manifest();
updateItemDetailDto.ItemId = Guid.NewGuid();
updateItemDetailDto.UnitsId = Guid.NewGuid();
manifest.ManifestId = Guid.NewGuid();

updateItemDetailDto.ItemDescription = "test";
updateItemDetailDto.Qty = 10;
updateItemDetailDto.ItemValue = 25.50M;
updateShipmentDetailDto.ItemDetails = new List<UpdateItemDetailDto>();
updateShipmentDetailDto.ItemDetails.Add(updateItemDetailDto);

_mapper.Map(updateShipmentDetailDto.ItemDetails, manifest.ItemDetails);

Console.WriteLine($"DTO Guid: {updateShipmentDetailDto.ItemDetails[0].ItemId}, Desc: {updateShipmentDetailDto.ItemDetails[0].ItemDescription}");
foreach (var item in manifest.ItemDetails)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Guid: {item.ItemId}, Desc: {item.ItemDescription}");   
}
Console.WriteLine($"Guid Manifest: {manifest.ManifestId}");
```

Comment: this is not the case. all other properties map correctly except for the properties which are not in the src get replaced by the default value. no point changing the property name here

Comment: I've set the ManifestID before map and it keep the guid when I print it after call Map ( now I dont change the property name, it's not necessary)

Comment: ItemId and UnitId are gettting mapped from source to destination. the answer provided creates new objects. thats not the case in mine